# How to keep the stack or the callers of async methods when this stack is quite big (node.js)?

Tags: debugging, node.js, stack

I have an app that has async into async many times and I'm having difficulties in knowing from where that call came and with which variables. There is any workaround?

The reason I'm having problems is because in qooxdoo the fireDataEvent is very complicated and I cannot get the callback method linked to the event.

thanks